# is inline still necessary since compilers will do inline automatically

Tags: c++, gcc

here is the code a1.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void)
{
        printf("hello world\n");
}

int main()
{

        func();
        return 0;
}
```

here is the code a2.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void func(void)
{
        printf("hello world\n");
}

int main()
{

        func();
        return 0;
}
```

they are only different with the key word 'inline'

then I compile them into assemble

```
g++ -S a1.cpp
g++ -S a2.cpp
```

the result is: inline does not work. function call remained in main.

then I compile them with optimizer

```
g++ -O2 -S a1.cpp
g++ -O2 -S a2.cpp
```

the result is : inline works in a2.s, but a1.s also replace the function call. it seems inline was added automatically.

so when inline is necessary when coding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)

Comment: @MysteriousUser No it doesn't.

Comment: `inline` allows the same function body to be visible in multiple compilation units without violating the One Definition Rule. Try your example with the function defined in two source files and see what happens without `inline` when you link.

Comment: `inline` has always been necessary to allow a function to be defined in multiple compilation units without breaching ODR. For the act of inserting code into call points rather than a call/jump to a separate definition, `inline` has never been necessary - at best, it is a hint that compilers have been permitted to - and often do - ignore.  As compiler/optimiser technology has improved, compilers can *typically* do a better job optimising code if they ignore `inline` (apart from meeting ODR) and produce less efficient code if forced to obey the programmer's use of `inline`.

Answer (score 5):

All the `inline` keyword does is allow a variable or function to be defined in multiple translation units without violating the One Definition Rule so long as all of the definitions are identical.  It has **absolutely nothing** to do with inlining *calls* to a function.  What it does is allow a function (or variable, since C++17) to be *defined* inline in a header file that gets included into multiple translation units instead of having to *declare* the function in the header and define it externally in exactly one translation unit.

Consider the following program:

header.hpp

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
}
```

a.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"
```

b.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main() {}
```

This program violates the One Definition Rule because `foo` is defined in two translation units.  Its is thus ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  Add the `inline` keyword to `foo` and this program will become correct and well defined.  `foo` will still be defined in multiple translation units, but since it's `inline` and those definitions are identical, the One Definition Rule is not violated.

---

Note that defining a function in a header like this *may* aid the compiler in inlining calls to the function (since the function's definition is visible at the point of the call in multiple translation units).  It's in no way required though.  Most modern compiler/linker toolchains implement some form of link-time optimization that can inline calls to functions defined in other translation units.

Comment: Technically, violation of ODR makes the program ill-formed. Not that there is practical difference between an ill-formed program (NDR) and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eerorika Fixed.  Technically correct is the best kind of correct after all.

Comment: I tested using header guards in the file with the definition and it still did not compile. Why does it skip the header guard and still go through to see that `void foo()` was already defined before?

Comment: @MysteriousUser Header include guards only stop a header from being included multiple times **within the same translation unit** (where a translation unit is usually a single .cpp file).  A function with a definition in a header will be defined in each translation unit that includes the header (unless you add some other preprocessor directives to avoid that, like some header-only libraries do), and such a function must be marked `inline` to avoid violating the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 0):

> so when inline is necessary when coding.

Short answer: Probably never (and never has been).

Long answer: Depends on your definition of "necessary". If it is necessary that some function call is expanded inline, and it is necessary to call that function from multiple translation units and the function cannot have internal linkage for whatever reason and you have to use an old compiler that doesn't support link time optimisation or that optimisation cannot be enabled for some other reason, then perhaps you have a case where it is necessary to define a function inline. Such cases are probably quite rare.

Note that since in this hypothetical case it is necessary for the calls to be expanded inline, you would necessarily also need some other technique to enforce that inline expansion. No standard way exists but there are language extensions.

Although they may not be necessary, inline definitions are used mostly because they are convenient and simple, especially in case of variables.

---

Note that there are two common (and contradictory) misconceptions about inline functions:

- That functions expand only calls to inline functions and/or that they do not expand calls to non-inline functions. You've proven this misconception wrong.
- That defining a function inline has nothing to do whether a function call may be expanded inline. It does have something to do with it: A compiler can expand a function call inline only if the function is defined in the same translation unit (this limitation does not apply to linkers). Since a non-inline function can only be defined in one TU, so can calls to it be inlined only within one TU (by a compiler). Furthermore, compilers do use inline declaration as a heuristic for determining whether to expand a call inline. Even today. At least based on source code; it could technically be dead code that is never called.