# Should I inline operators == and != in case when operator!=() uses negation of operator==()

Tags: c++, micro-optimization

I am using this simple example to illustrate a problem in which I am trying to optimize stack usage. Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
// Something.h
struct Something {
  int val;

  bool operator==(const Something& rhs);
  bool operator!=(const Something& rhs);
};

// Something.cpp
bool Something::operator==(const Something& rhs) {
  return val == rhs.val;
}

bool Something::operator!=(const Something& rhs) {
  return !(*this == rhs);
}
```

Calling operator!=() will push two stack frames onto the stack (one for != and another for ==).
Should I inline operator!=() so that both == and != use same amount of stack?

Comment: Probably you shouldn't care about a micro-optimization like this one. Anyway, if you really need to save amount of space in the stack you may do `return val != rhs.val` instead of calling the `operator==()`. Additionally, if you need to optimize the stack usage so desperately then you might have a X/Y problem.

Comment: Unless you're using an older version of C++ that doesn't support it, you usually want to overload the spaceship (`<=>`) operator, and let the compiler synthesize others from that as needed.

Comment: FWIW, `inline` doesn't actually mean inline my function.  It's actualy use is for the linker so it knows that duplicate symbols can be merged and it's not an error.  It's only a hint to the compiler to inline the function.  Most/all compilers should inline this code as is with optimizations turned on.

Comment: The spaceship operator is part of C++20, which no compiler fully supports as of right now. It will be good to familiarize with it, but the support isn't there yet on the trunk, let alone "in the wild."

Comment: @sweenish both gcc and clang fully support the 3-way comparison operator (spaceship operator) as well as defaulted comparator operators. https://godbolt.org/z/fP4rf1

Comment: @bolov I wasn't speaking directly to the the spaceship. Although I see how it reads that way, looking at it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **use link-time optimization (LTO) so either of them can fully inline into the call-site**, especially when it's near-trivial like this.

But if you don't want to use LTO for cross-file inlining, then yes it would be a good idea to put the `operator !=` `return !(*this == rhs);` definition **inside the class definition in the `.h`**) so it's visible to every caller and can inline there into files that just included the `.h`.  Then the asm for callers will call the same `operator==` definition but use the result the opposite way.  e.g. `test al,al` / `jnz` instead of `jz` if you're branching on the result.

If you don't use LTO and don't make the definition visible for compile-time inlining, the best that will happen is the compiler will inline `operator==` into the `operator!=` stand-alone definition when compiling that one `.cpp`.  Then you have two similar-sized functions in the machine code that differ only by one boolean inversion.  Users of these functions (from other files) will call one or the other, so they're both taking up space in your I-cache / code footprint.

---

### Example

https://godbolt.org/z/e88nGj

```
// Something.h
struct Something {
  int val;

  bool operator==(const Something& rhs);
  bool operator!=(const Something& rhs) { return !(*this == rhs); }
};
// simulated #include for one-file demo purposes

// Some other .cpp file, operator== definition not visible.
int foo(Something &a, Something &b)
{
    if (a != b) {
        return a.val;
    } else { 
        return b.val;
    }
}
```

GCC -O3 for x86-64 ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/613Eaq)) compiles as follows:

```
foo(Something&, Something&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsi
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi           # save the pointers in call-preserved regs
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    Something::operator==(Something const&)
        test    al, al                # set FLAGS from the bool retval
        cmovne  rbx, rbp              # select the right pointer
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbx]  # and load from it

        add     rsp, 8                # epilogue
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Notice that this code calls `Something::operator==` which couldn't inline at compile time (it could at link time with LTO).  It just uses `cmovne` instead of `cmove` if it had called an actual separate `operator!=`.

**The `operator!=` inlined to literally zero extra cost,** and all calls to either function use the same stand-alone definition, saving code footprint.  Good for performance especially if you have code that uses both operators enough for it to stay hot in cache.

Of course, letting `operator==` inline as well would give significant savings when the class is just an `int`; no call at all is often a lot better because there's no need to preserve registers around something.

(Of course in this case my example is too trivial: if they *are* equal, then it can still return `a.val` because it knows that's the same as `b.val`.  So if you uncomment the `operator==` definition in the Godbolt link, `foo` compiles to `mov  eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]` / `ret`, never even touching `b`.)

Answer (score 3):

You have a misconception about what the `inline` keyword does. For clarification, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379889/15284149

Answering your question, yes it is probably faster to "inline", which is why the compiler will in fact automatically optimize it (as long as you have at least -O1): https://godbolt.org/z/9Kn3hE

Comment: The question didn't say they were talking about the `inline` keyword; I assume they meant actually arrange for `operator!=` to be able to truly inline into callers.  (e.g. by defining it in the .h, inside the class definition.)