# How does the Delphi 2009 compiler handle recursive inline methods?

Tags: delphi, recursion, delphi-2009, inline-method

Do "[What's wrong with using inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830/what-is-wrong-with-using-inline-functions)" and "[Can a recursive function be inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190232/can-a-recursive-function-be-inline)" apply to Delphi inline functions? Furthermore, does anyone know how recursive inline functions are handled in Delphi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is probably not since inline is only a suggestion, but lets find out.

A simple recursive factorial routine:

```
function Factorial(const aNum: cardinal): cardinal;
begin
  if aNum > 1 then
    Result := Factorial(aNum - 1) * aNum
  else
    Result := 1;
end;
```

Here is the disassembly of the call to it:

```
// fact := Factorial(5);
mov eax,$00000005
call Factorial
mov ebx,eax
```

And the disassembly of the routine itself:

```
// 9: begin
push ebx
mov ebx,eax
// 10: if aNum > 1 then
cmp ebx,$01
jbe $0040ab30
// 11: Result := Factorial(aNum - 1) * aNum
mov eax,ebx
dec eax
call Factorial
imul ebx
pop ebx
ret 
// 13: Result := 1;
0040ab30: mov eax,$00000001
// 14: end;
pop ebx
ret
```

Now we make it **inline** and see what is different in the call:

```
// 21: fact := Factorial(5);
mov eax,$00000005
call Factorial
mov ebx,eax
```

And the routine itself:

```
// 9: begin
push ebx
mov ebx,eax
// 10: if aNum > 1 then
cmp ebx,$01
jbe $0040ab30
// 11: Result := Factorial(aNum - 1) * aNum
mov eax,ebx
dec eax
call Factorial
imul ebx
pop ebx
ret     
// 13: Result := 1;
0040ab30: mov eax,$00000001
// 14: end;
pop ebx
ret
```

And they both appear the same to me, so I am going to stick with my original hypothesis and say they are not supported.

**BTW**: this is in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. RE: "In Delphi 2009" I was looking through my Object Pascal reference for Delphi 7, apparently inline has been a forward-compatible keyword for a long time, it just never did anything back then.

Comment: Seems like I remember seeing it a while ago too.

Comment: "Inline" used to be how you could put raw machine code into your functions. Now you just use "asm" blocks, and if you want instructions that the compiler doesn't know, you insert the bytes with DB, DW, and DD instructions.